# Where are the sources for rails-2.3.5 and rack-1.0.1?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, installation

I'm trying to upgrade a rails application which requires rails-2.3.5 which in turn seems to require rack-1.0.1.  Many (many!) attempts of each of the following hasn't worked:

```
# gem install rails -v=2.3.5
ERROR:  could not find gem rails locally or in a repository
```

or

```
# gem install rails -v=2.3.5 --source http://gems.rubyforge.org
WARNING:  RubyGems 1.2+ index not found for:
    http://gems.rubyforge.org/

RubyGems will revert to legacy indexes degrading performance.
Bulk updating Gem source index for: http://gems.rubyforge.org/
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Gem::RemoteSourceException)
    Error fetching remote gem cache: SocketError: getaddrinfo: Name or service not known (http://gems.rubyforge.org/yaml)
```

or substituting http://gems.rubyonrails.org.  When I tried http://gems.github.org I get an index error.

Simply trying a `gems update rails` succeeds as a command, but it installs version 2.3.3.

**Why would any of this not be working?**

For reference:

```
# cat /root/.gemrc
---
:benchmark: false
:verbose: true
:update_sources: true
:sources:
- http://gems.rubyonrails.org
- http://gems.opscode.com
:bulk_threshold: 1000
:backtrace: false
```

(Is the installer really at version 2?)

Comment: Get rid of gems.github, they aren't supporting it anymore: http://gems.github.com/

Comment: Have you tried updating RubyGems? You can use any of the methods listed here to do so: http://wiki.joyent.com/all-accelerators:kb:rubygems

Comment: @Intelekshual: `gem update --system` gives `Nothing to update`.  `gem install rubygems-update` gives `ERROR: could not find gem rubygems-update ...`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I came back two (2) hours later and:

```
# gem install rails -v=2.3.5 --source http://gems.rubyforge.org
Successfully installed activesupport-2.3.5
Successfully installed activerecord-2.3.5
Successfully installed rack-1.0.1
Successfully installed actionpack-2.3.5
Successfully installed actionmailer-2.3.5
Successfully installed activeresource-2.3.5
Successfully installed rails-2.3.5
7 gems installed
...
```

It worked.

Truly weird.  It would be nice if the error messages could be a little more informative.

Comment: It sounds like there was a problem with the source. Could there have maybe been a firewall or a web filter that was blocking the request?

Comment: I think the source was just busy.  Even a 404 error would have been helpful.