# how to get trunk code from repository? (redmine,svn)

Tags: svn, git, redmine, turnkeylinux.org

I am using [turnkey redmine](http://www.turnkeylinux.org/redmine) and I can log in and do stuff so everything is working fine.

I need to test some features from the trunk and I have no idea how I can install redmine from [trunk repository](http://www.redmine.org/projects/redmine/repository/revisions/3859)

both & svn clients are working from the command line.

Comment: I think it has nothing to do with svn/git.  What you need to know is after getting the source code, how perform building.  I believe there will be related documents available either in the source or on the web site

Comment: well, I use svn at work to get the latest build. I run svn and that's it. I thought it would be the same. Why should I build web application?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This [article](http://www.turnkeylinux.org/forum/support/20100104/how-upgrade-redmine-087) helped me upgrade my turnkey install, which is what I think your trying to do.

Scoot down to about a third of the way through the article to *Danilo Pires* submission entitled ***"The Upgrade (0.8.4 to 0.9.4) process in 17 simple steps"***

I noted a few exceptions:

- the `plugins_assets` directory didn't exist, create it in between steps 7 & 8.
- steps 10 and 11 worked better when I added: `--source http://gems.rubyforge.org` to the end of the command.
- before step 12, issue: `rake config/initializers/session_store.rb`

Also, steps 10 and 11 can fail with a terribly misinformative error message.  Keep trying the command (it does work) until the server decides to give you some sugar.  Could be hours though.  See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2998758/where-are-the-sources-for-rails-2-3-5-and-rack-1-0-1).

Answer (score 1):

[Turnkey Redmine](http://www.turnkeylinux.org/redmine) is an instance of [TurnkeyLinux](http://www.turnkeylinux.org/), a [virtual appliance](http://www.turnkeylinux.org/virtual-appliance) (a pre-integrated, self contained system that is made by combining a software application server software -- here Redmine -- with an OS -- here Ubuntu).
Redmine is already installed.

That is different from [Redmine](http://www.redmine.org/) itself: if you get its [latest release](http://www.redmine.org/wiki/redmine/Download), you still need to [install it](http://www.redmine.org/wiki/redmine/HowTos).

But if by "installing redmine" you mean "installing some extra plugin to the redmine currently installed in the Turnkey virtual appliance I use, then you need to access to the Redmine instance within said virtual appliance.

Comment: redmine is already installed and working. By install I meant checkout latest trunk version of source code.

Comment: @Radek: so you want to upgrade the existing Redmine installed in your Turkey Redmine virtual appliance?

Comment: I am not sure about the terminology but I was told that I should try some features that are only in trunk code. So I want to install/checkout/have trunk code of redmine

Comment: Do you realize that it's "Turnkey" but throughout your answer you've written "Turkey"?

Comment: @Dan: I didn't realize it at all :) Now Fixed.